# Primary and secondary actions on iOS table view cells

Tags: mobile, tables, ios, lists, material-design

What is the iOS equivalent of a Material list item with primary and secondary actions? (I'm an Android guy)

[image: Material list item]

A possible solution for the primary action would be something like this:

[image: iOS table view cell]

But what about the secondary action(s)?

The Podcast app for example uses three dots to display an Action Sheet, but there is no distinction between primary and secondary action.

In my case the primary action is very important (buy tickets) compared to the secondary action. Also, I'd like not to use "hidden" actions underneath a swipeable table view cell because of bad discoverability.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

Here's what I eventually came up with:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option, which has been available since iOS 3 but not often seen in practice, is to set the cell's [accessory type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcellaccessorytype) to `detailDisclosureButton`. It will show both the 'info' button and the chevron. The info button is it's own tappable area, and can be used for the secondary action; tapping the cell outside this area (primary action) will have the same effect as selecting the row in a normal table view.

[image]

<sub>([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18740594/4751173))</sub>

It's possible to add an image to the cell, left of the labels, like the folder in your first picture, with the cell's `image` property.

Otherwise, you need to go for a custom table view cell, which has the benefit that you can customize it further (add more labels and/or images).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I've update my original question to show my own solution. I'm not an iOS developer, but I guess this will require building our own customized table view cells.

Comment: @gregory yes, that design will require customized cells. That's not too hard, fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is pretty good!

You could also consider placing your share action in a swipe-able menu. True, it's not the most discoverable option, but given how default iOS apps like Notes and Mail are using gestures in TableViewCells for a long time now, Swiping a cell for quicker access to more options isn't a bad idea, since it's sort of an expected behaviour in TableViewCells in iOS.

-However, as per the HiG this should only be done if the share action is available else-where as well. Say, if the user taps on the cell and the appearing view has a share option too, you can use the swipe menu to provide users with a shortcut to that.